# UnicodeEncodeError in python3.4.2?

Tags: python-3.x, ascii, chr

Hi i have the following code in python3.4.2:

```
s='416f1c7918f83a4f1922d86df5e78348'; w="0123456789abcdef"; x=''.join([chr(w.index(s[i])*16+w.index(s[i+1])) if(i%2==0) else '' for i in range(len(s))]); print(x);
```

and it shows this error
`UnicodeEncodeError: 
'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf8' in position 5: ordinal not in range
(128)`

Why is this happening ? isn't chr in python3 supposed to take more than 128 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too much work.

```
>>> binascii.unhexlify(s)
b'Ao\x1cy\x18\xf8:O\x19"\xd8m\xf5\xe7\x83H'
```

Comment: not even the question ... , if you want to decode(encoding) it shows the same error .

Comment: The problem is that `chr()` is for characters, but you don't have characters.

Comment: can you elaborate more? I don't understand "you don't have characters" ...

Comment: You have bytes. The difference matters now that you're using 3.x.

Comment: so what should i do then?

Comment: Stop using `chr()` and start using bytes. Or do it the right way in the first place.

Comment: And? Decode it using the appropriate charset once you've converted it.